# Maintain binary representation when decoding invalid UTF-8 in Swift

Tags: swift, unicode, utf-8

I want to convert a `Data` into a `String` using the `utf8` encoding, regardless of whether the `Data` contains invalid characters:

```swift
var cafe = "Café".data(using: .utf8)!
cafe.count // 5
cafe.removeLast() // remove the "e", making parts of the string invalid utf8
cafe.count // 4
let s = String(decoding: cafe, as: UTF8.self) // "Caf�"
s.data(using: .utf8)?.count // 6
```

In the above code, I convert invalid utf8 into `String`, but the converted string contains different data than the original binary representation. Is there a way to have the string be a simple "view" of the data?

EDIT: The objective is to be able to search and replace (and run regular expressions) within a binary file (e.g. a compiled executables with a section of it being strings). Compiled executables most likely contain bytes that can't be encoded as utf8.

Comment: In the above example, are you just trying to remove the accent mark from the 'e'?

Comment: @Rob ah no. The last code unit of the utf8 representation is the `e` (the in-memory representation is `('C', 'a', 'f', <accent modifier>, 'e')`). When I remove the last element, the `e` is removed but the accent is still there, which makes the string invalid.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding why you'd want to do that. Your objective is still unclear.

Comment: The objective is to be able to search and replace (and run regular expressions) within a binary file (e.g. a compiled executables with a section of it being strings). Compiled executables most likely contain bytes that can't be encoded as utf8. That's the motivation for asking this question.

Comment: If the well-formed text is all ASCII (or a single byte encoding compatible with Unicode), you could always decode in that encoding, but I guess that's not the case?

Comment: The problem is that parts of the input is invalid Unicode and parts of it is well-formed text. I’m unable to find a way to decode only parts of the input (or find which part of the input is well-formed)

Answer (score 0):

***Is there a way to have the string be a simple "view" of the data?***

No. Swift String is intended to hold a sequence of valid Unicode code points.
If you want to keep *the original binary representation*, you should better hold the Data.

What do you really want to do with such invalid data?

Comment: I want to search and replace (and potentially run regular expressions) on binary data (e.g. compiled executables with a section of it being strings). Is there a way to achieve that without implementing my own search and replace functions?

Comment: @Ben, no. NSRegularExpression is based on ICU implementation of regular expression working with Unicode. You may need your own.